# Viewport for the textbox is not showing properly using singlechildscrollview in flutter

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

hi guys to all who can help me figure my code,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:survey/widgets/widgetlist.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
class Item {
   Item(this.name);
   String name;
}



class createnewsurv extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _createnewsurvState createState() => _createnewsurvState();
}

class _createnewsurvState extends State<createnewsurv> {

  TextEditingController _textcontroller = new TextEditingController();
  int surveyquestionnum = 1;
  Item selectedUser;
  List<Item> users = <Item>[
     Item('Sample 1'),
     Item('Sample 2'),
     Item('Sample 3'),
     Item('Sample 4'),
  ];
  List<Item> users2 = <Item>[
    Item('Sample EMOJI 1'),
    Item('Sample EMOJI 2'),
    Item('Sample EMOJI 3'),
    Item('Sample EMOJI 4'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget _dropdownbutton (List<Item> userlist){
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15.0) 
        ),
      ),
      child: DropdownButton<Item>(
        underline: SizedBox(),
        isExpanded: true,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        hint:  Text("  SELECT FROM DROPDOWN"),
        value: selectedUser,
        onChanged: (Item Value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedUser = Value;
          });
        },
        items: userlist.map((Item user) {
          return  DropdownMenuItem<Item>(
            value: user,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                Text(
                  user.name,
                  style:  TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double _height = logicalSize.height;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("CREATE A NEW SURVEY ",style: txtttitsize),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(" SURVEY TITLE",style: txtttitsize),
                    ),
                    _dropdownbutton(users),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(" SELECT EMOJI SET",style: txtttitsize),
                    ),
                    _dropdownbutton(users2),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(" SURVEY QUESTION #$surveyquestionnum",style: txtttitsize),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      autocorrect: true,
                      controller: _textcontroller,
                      maxLines: 10,
                      onSaved: (value){
                      },
                      validator: (val){
                        if(val.isEmpty){
                          return "This page Cannot be Blank!";
                        }else{
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "QUESTION",
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
                          )
                      ),
                    )
                  ]
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

this is an incomplete code, but if you noticed and tried running this, it will show 
2 dropdown widget which for some reason when i select it crash showing ''there should be exactly one item with [DropDownButton]'s Value: error,

and the next one is the textform field, which i am hoping when i wrapped it on singlescrollview when somebody type it should or let the viewport focus its screen to the textbox while typing,
but its already on the third line and its already blocked by the keyboard,

i may be wrong but how can i use singlescrollview properly on this? or if there is an alternative widget to give this textbox a chance to be viewed properly by the user while they type?

Update

[image][image]

This error appears after clicking any drop down button.
I updated the code with the suggested answer and its still the same for me .

Comment: Error says that there should be a option (for `DropdownButton`) with a value equals to `DropdownButton`'s value. For example if you pass `5` as value but your options are `1, 2, 3, 4`, that error will throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Two `_dropdownbutton` use the same `selectedUser` cause this error 
You can use  `List<Item> selectedUser = [null, null];` to keep result 
and pass `index` to function like this `_dropdownbutton(users, 0)`

code snippet

```
 Widget _dropdownbutton(List<Item> userlist, int index) {
 ...
  child: DropdownButton<Item>(
        underline: SizedBox(),
        isExpanded: true,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        hint: Text("  SELECT FROM DROPDOWN"),
        value: selectedUser[index],
        onChanged: (Item Value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedUser[index] = Value;
          });
        },
 ...

 _dropdownbutton(users, 0),

 _dropdownbutton(users2, 1),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:survey/widgets/widgetlist.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Item {
  Item(this.name);
  String name;
}

class createnewsurv extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _createnewsurvState createState() => _createnewsurvState();
}

class _createnewsurvState extends State<createnewsurv> {
  TextEditingController _textcontroller = new TextEditingController();
  int surveyquestionnum = 1;
  List<Item> selectedUser = [null, null];
  List<Item> users;
  List<Item> users2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    users = <Item>[
      Item('Sample 1'),
      Item('Sample 2'),
      Item('Sample 3'),
      Item('Sample 4'),
    ];

    users2 = <Item>[
      Item('Sample EMOJI 1'),
      Item('Sample EMOJI 2'),
      Item('Sample EMOJI 3'),
      Item('Sample EMOJI 4'),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget _dropdownbutton(List<Item> userlist, int index) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
      ),
      child: DropdownButton<Item>(
        underline: SizedBox(),
        isExpanded: true,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        hint: Text("  SELECT FROM DROPDOWN"),
        value: selectedUser[index],
        onChanged: (Item Value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedUser[index] = Value;
          });
        },
        items: userlist.map((Item user) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<Item>(
            value: user,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  user.name,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double _height = logicalSize.height;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "CREATE A NEW SURVEY ",
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        " SURVEY TITLE",
                      ),
                    ),
                    _dropdownbutton(users, 0),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        " SELECT EMOJI SET",
                      ),
                    ),
                    _dropdownbutton(users2, 1),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        " SURVEY QUESTION #$surveyquestionnum",
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      autocorrect: true,
                      controller: _textcontroller,
                      maxLines: 10,
                      onSaved: (value) {},
                      validator: (val) {
                        if (val.isEmpty) {
                          return "This page Cannot be Blank!";
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "QUESTION",
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25))),
                    )
                  ]),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: createnewsurv()),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi sir chunhunghan, it still end up the same issue for me after copying and pasting your code,,apart from this do you think you can help me fix the issue as well on the textformfield? when i type and its already on the third line the keyboard is blocking its way for you to see what you are typing

Comment: oh wait, im sorry i found the issue on the drop down, it works now,, i guess if you may help me with that textformfield,, im good to go,, im really happy and thank you i wish i can pay you back with your kindness after this :)

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you.

Comment: Sorry. The reason is nested Scaffold. You can directly use home: createnewsurv(), because I use home: MyHomePage () -> createnewsurv(). there are two Scaffold.  After directly use home: createnewsurv(), it works without block at third line.

Comment: thank you , i have ticked this as working, although im not sure yet why the singlescrollchildview didnt work for me to allow typing on the text box, is it really because i have two scaffold here?

Comment: When trying to fix another stackoverflow question yesterday. I did encounter  singlescrollchildview with padding issue.  singlescrollchildview  maxscrollextent did not include whole length. only current viewport length. and  I did not find  solution.

Comment: but to understand the purpose of single scroll childview is to let the user focus on what they are typing on the screen so that they can see it right? or is there any alternatives, mine as you can see gets blocked by the keyboard when you go to the third line or 4th line